# Forcing to first update then select in a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this procedure in MySQL (don't bother to figure it out what it does, just watch the part where the cursor is opened)

```
/* PROCEDURE 1 : Post notification */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddNotificationOnPosts;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddNotificationOnPosts`(arg_from_user INT(11),arg_on_post_id INT(11),arg_in_group_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE insert_result INT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT user_id 
        FROM user_rights 
        WHERE user_rights.right = 101 AND user_rights.group_id  = arg_in_group_id 
        ORDER BY user_id DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    IF(arg_from_user IS NULL OR arg_from_user = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSEIF(arg_on_post_id IS NULL OR arg_on_post_id = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSEIF(arg_in_group_id IS NULL OR arg_in_group_id = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSE
        SELECT count(notification_id) FROM notifications_posts 
        WHERE 
        from_user = arg_from_user AND
        on_post_id = arg_on_post_id AND
        in_group_id = arg_in_group_id
        INTO num_rows;
    END IF;

    IF num_rows = 0
    THEN
        INSERT INTO notifications_posts(from_user,on_post_id,in_group_id) VALUES(arg_from_user,arg_on_post_id,arg_in_group_id);
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO insert_result;

        IF insert_result > 0 
        THEN        
            /* Increment the notifications for every user*/
            OPEN c1;
            read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH c1 INTO var_user_id;
                    IF done THEN
                        LEAVE read_loop;
                    ELSE
                        IF NOT(var_user_id = arg_from_user)
                        THEN

                            /* UPDATING */
                            UPDATE user_info SET notifications = notifications + 1 WHERE user_info.user_id = var_user_id;

                            /* SELECTING RESULT */
                            SELECT
                            user_info.user_id,
                            messages,
                            tasks,
                            notifications,
                            messages+tasks+notifications AS total
                            FROM user_rights
                            INNER
                                JOIN user_info
                                ON user_info.user_id = user_rights.user_id
                            WHERE user_rights.right = 101 AND user_rights.group_id  = arg_in_group_id ;

                        END IF;
                    END IF;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE c1;


        ELSE
            SELECT "0" AS response;
        END IF;

    ELSE
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and in this part

```
            /* Increment the notifications for every user*/
            OPEN c1;
            read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH c1 INTO var_user_id;
                    IF done THEN
                        LEAVE read_loop;
                    ELSE
                        IF NOT(var_user_id = arg_from_user)
                        THEN

                            /* UPDATING */
                            UPDATE user_info SET notifications = notifications + 1 WHERE user_info.user_id = var_user_id;

                            /* SELECTING RESULT */
                            SELECT
                            user_info.user_id,
                            messages,
                            tasks,
                            notifications,
                            messages+tasks+notifications AS total
                            FROM user_rights
                            INNER
                                JOIN user_info
                                ON user_info.user_id = user_rights.user_id
                            WHERE user_rights.right = 101 AND user_rights.group_id  = arg_in_group_id ;

                        END IF;
                    END IF;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE c1;
```

the procedure selects data, then update it (believe me, i'm dead serious), and i really need to select after, because i'm generating an `XML` with the altered data, so:

1 Why is selecting then updating, because i see that select is underneath the update

2 Who had this "brilliant idea" to make it this way?

Thank you.

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce the problem.  Also, when you are talking about "who had this brilliant idea", what are you talking about?  Am I supposed to know the author of the stored procedure?

Comment: good point, no, but trust me it is very wired that it first does the selecting, then the update, because i'm trying to fetch the data with PHP ( http://codepad.org/Uvg6hT8P )

Comment: "don't bother to figure it out what it does, just watch the part where the cursor is opened" -> You could write a very simple test procedure, without the logic of your algorithm, so we can concentrate just on the issue you are pointing out.

Comment: you are right, but i taught that there is something wrong in my code that does this, understand?

Comment: ok, but this is the right situation to try a test procedure, so you can see if the cause of the problem is your code or MySQL behaviour.

Comment: i have researched and this are my results, http://codepad.org/bC6yN2z3 , apparently i see that a simple procedure does first update then select, depending on the order of the queries ...

Answer (score 1):

When you've got in one batch update/delete and something else in sql-server, it is completely indeterministic in which order "commands" will be execute.
The solution to this problem is to put "update" in different batch, by using "exec" statement. So try use:

```
exec('UPDATE user_info SET notifications = notifications + 1 WHERE user_info.user_id =' + var_user_id);
```

It should work now.

Comment: is this available in mysql? and i have researched and this are my results, http://codepad.org/bC6yN2z3 , apparently i see that a simple procedure does first update then select, depending on the order of the queries ...

Comment: sorry, in my mind i skipped that's mysql. In this case my advice is to make stored procedure with update, and then use it in the loop. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem: the `SELECT` statement must be outside of the `CURSOR LOOP`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd that the update and select are executed in the right order, but the select could not "see" the result of the update due to transaction isolation.

I would suggest the following solution to workaround this problem and improve the performance by eliminating the join in the subsequent select:

```
set @notification = 0;

/* UPDATING */
UPDATE user_info SET notifications = @notification := notifications + 1 WHERE user_info.user_id = var_user_id;

/* SELECTING RESULT */
SELECT
     user_info.user_id,
     messages,
     tasks,
     notifications,
     messages+tasks+@notifications AS total
 FROM user_rights
WHERE user_rights.right = 101 AND user_rights.group_id  = arg_in_group_id ;
```